# If the fundamental group is finite, any path connected cover has finite fibres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $B$ be a space with a path connected cover $p: E \to B$. Let $b_0 \in B$ and assume $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ is finite. Then $p^{-1}(b_0)$ is finite.

Assume that $p^{-1}(b_0)$ is infinite and write $\pi_1(B, b_0) = \left\{[\gamma_1], [\gamma_2], \dots, [\gamma_n]\right\}$. For each $[\gamma_j] \in \pi_1(B, b_0)$, we can pick infinitely many points $e_0, e_1, \dots$ in disjoint open sets of $E$ such that $p(e_i) = b_0$ for all $i$ and lift the homotopy equivalence class $[\gamma_j]$ to a homotopy equivalence class $[\gamma_j]_{e_i}$. I am lost as to proceed from here.

Comment: Are you following an algebraic topology book? If so, you should read about the correspondence between subgroups of the fundamental group and covering spaces. Also, try to prove this first for the universal covering space.

Comment: I am not reading an algebraic topology book, only Munkres. This was a suggested exercise for my class.

Comment: The forward direction is easier to reason about. Suppose the fiber of $b_0$ is infinite. Pick a point $x$ in the fiber of $b_0$ and consider the paths $y\to x \subset E$ for all $y$ in the fiber of $b_0$. Those map down to elements of the fundamental group in $B$. by PHP some two of these are homotopic, lift that homotopy, arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the important assumptions we have:

1. $E$ is path-connected
2. $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ is finite

Let's try to use these two facts as directly as possible.

First, if $p^{-1}(b_0)$ is empty, then we are done. Otherwise, fix some point $e_0 \in p^{-1}(b_0)$. Now for each $e \in p^{-1}(b_0)$, pick some path $\gamma_e : [0,1] \to E$ such that $\gamma_e(0) = e_0$ and $\gamma_e(1) = e$.
(We have now used the assumption that $E$ is path-connected!)

Next, consider the set $X := \{[p \circ \gamma_e] : e \in p^{-1}(b_0)\}$. This is a subset of $\pi_1(B,b_0)$, and thus is finite. So, there exists a natural number $n$ and points $e_1, \dots, e_n \in p^{-1}(b_0)$ such that $$X = \{[p \circ \gamma_{e_0}], \dots, [p \circ \gamma_{e_n}]\}.$$
(We have now used the assumption that $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ is finite!)

We now claim that $p^{-1}(b_0) = \{e_0, \dots, e_n\}$. So, let $e \in p^{-1}(b_0)$ be arbitrary. Then $[p \circ \gamma_e] \in X$, so there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[p \circ \gamma_e] = [p \circ \gamma_{e_n}]$.

**Claim** (For you to fill in!) $\gamma_e$ is homotopic to $\gamma_{e_n}$ (rel. endpoints), and thus $e = e_n$.

(*Hint: use the homotopy lifting property*)

This will complete the proof!